# Windows 7, PC Shut Down when CPU is HOT!

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Recently I installed a copy of Windows 7 Professional on my Acer 5735Z Laptop and when the CPU (Dual Core T3200) gets Hot the Laptop is Shutting Down. So my question is: Does Windows 7 has a Protection System or something like that? If yes, how do I disable it?

PS: Windows 7 x64 Professional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more likely to be your motherboard, and [you don't want to disable it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1qr6lZ52-k). It's a safety feature.

If your CPU is overheating, you might have airflow issues, so clean any dust out of your laptop's vents, and see if it still happens.

Comment: Yeah well I don`t think is a vent issue because I have this problem when I installed Windows 7 on Windows XP...no problem. Anyway i`ll try to clean the dust. Can I use a vacuum cleaner?

Comment: If it has a "blow" mode and can be turned to "low", probably. I tend to just blow, but I don't own a laptop myself so aren't the best person to ask :P

Comment: You may also want to try checking your CPU temp. with SpeedFan, or similar software, just to make sure. (I idle at about 40c, but this is a desktop)

Comment: Yeah it seems like is a vent problem, Core 0: 89C , Core 1: 87C damn...thanks.

Comment: Woah, that's hot! My friend had a similar issue lately, where his CPU was automatically downclocking, so you might get some extra performance out of it now, even :P

Comment: I didn`t overclocked my CPU I`ll try to clean the Vents if nothing happens then i`ll downclock it.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not handled by OS level. It is handled by Hardware level.**

In some BIOS settings you can see a setting to adjust max CPU temperature. Like 65/75 C. You may use that to change the threshold value.

Check the CPU fan speed in BIOS setup. If it is too low or Zero you have a trouble with the CPU fan.

A troublesome system fans may be another reason for heavy system box temperatures.

And some invalid bios settings may lead to heat your CPU. Loading fail safe defaults might be a good way to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is **NOT** to disable the safety feature, since your laptop won't live for a very long time that way. You can try reattaching the processor after adding new thermal paste, but I don't think this is going to bring it down too much though. The best is to send is back to Acer.

This is pretty common with Acer laptops, since I know a friend as well with the exact same problem, also on an acer laptop.

If it happens while playing games (heavy operation), the best you can do now is switch to playstation 2 or xbox 360, or just use a desktop computer.

Comment: The problem is I don`t play Games. I`m a web-dev so I use Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE6, IE7, IE8, Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Flash, E-Text Editor, File Zilla, Winamp, Yahoo and AIM at the same time...poor CPU :))

Comment: Well, I think the ram memory is suffering a little more hehe. I also develop websites and applications, which isn't really that bad for the cpu, unless you are compiling huge applications with google web toolkit or doing some real sick javascripting. I never found my pc turning hot doing work so I guess you got a real problem with the cooling.

I suggest you get it fixed asap, the hotter your cpu, the less lifetime, that's basically why turns itself off.

PS: E text editor, that's one windows application I really miss on ubuntu

Comment: Only 2.30GB of RAM in use when I have all of this Programs in use :D and the CPU`s like... 60-73% :)) I think i`ll buy 2 external fans...